# How to query nested XML file in AWS Athena via Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, etl, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I want the nested XML file to query from AWS Athena using AWS glue.

```
<Files>
<File>
<Charges>
<charge>
<FRNo>99988881111</FRNo>
<amount>25.0</amount>
<Date>2019-02-25</Date>
<chargeType>Recur</chargeType>
<phoneNo>4444000012</phoneNo>
</charge>

<charge>
<FRNo>99988881111</FRNo>
<amount>40.0</amount>
<Date>2019-02-25</Date>
<chargeType>Recur</chargeType>
<phoneNo>4444000012</phoneNo>
</charge>

</Charges>


<FRNo>99988881111</FRNo>
<address>New YORK</address>
<amount>111</amount>
<DN>100000</DN>
 <name>Rite</name>
<phoneNo>4444000012</phoneNo>
<tax>8.0</tax>
</File>
</Files>
```

Like this I have some 10k records. I think we have to do some modification in ETL job. Let me know for any other information.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Amazon Athena does not support the XML file format. You may find the list of supported formats here: [Supported SerDes and Data Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/supported-serdes.html)

Since AWS Glue supports XML as an ETL input format (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html), you may first convert your data from XML to JSON and then query the JSON data using Athena.

Answer (score 1):

Athena cannot process XML file(s) directly. So, we need to any of the format's (CSV/JSON/etc..) which Athena supports.


1) Crawl XML file in Glue (Give proper rowTag value)
2) Write a Glue job to convert XML to CSV/JSON 
3) Crawl converted CSV/JSON